# On the relationship between the Sylvester criterion and the Schur complement for positive semi-definiteness of a matrix via LMI

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

For some context, I see that when people try to determine the positive definiteness of a matrix, the [Sylvester criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) can be of great help since the determinant is easy to calculate. For the case of block partition matrix, people seems to love the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).

In convex optimization, I have run into a situation where the set of inequality constraints $$ {x_1} \ge 0, \qquad {x_2} \ge 0, \qquad 1 - {x_1}{x_2} \le 0 $$ has been reformulated into a single [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI) constraint.

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{x_1}}&1\\
1&{{x_2}}
\end{array}} \right]\succcurlyeq0$$

This gives me a feeling that the Sylvester crtiterion and the Schur complement are some how related.

1. So is there a relationship between Sylvester criterion and Schur complement for positive semidefiniteness of a matrix?
2. If this relationship exist, can we use this to reformulate non-convex constraints as LMI?